# unable to initialize terraform via githubaction workflow

Tags: terragrunt

I am trying to run my code using githubaction workflow but anytime i run the workflow I am getting this error

> Checking the latest version of Terraform Downloading Terraform v1.0.4
> Successfully downloaded Terraform v1.0.4 Unzipping Terraform v1.0.4
> /src/main.sh: line 166: cd: /github/workspace//stage/dev-env: No such
> file or directory Successfully unzipped Terraform v1.0.4 Checking the
> latest version of Terragrunt Downloading Terragrunt v0.31.4
> Successfully downloaded Terragrunt v0.31.4 Moving Terragrunt v0.31.4
> to PATH Successfully moved Terragrunt v0.31.4 init: info: initializing
> Terragrunt configuration in /stage/dev-env init: error: failed to
> initialize Terragrunt configuration in /stage/dev-env
> time=2021-08-16T22:16:53Z level=error msg=Error reading file at path
> /github/workspace/terragrunt.hcl: open
> /github/workspace/terragrunt.hcl: no such file or directory
> time=2021-08-16T22:16:53Z level=error msg=Unable to determine
> underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1

I dont understand what its saying about workspace

This is how my code and directory layout looks like.Thanks guys

Stage/dev-env/main.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "test" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
  Name = "GithAction"
```

}

stage/dev-env/provider.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
   aws = {
    source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    version = "~> 3.0"
}
```

}
}

stage/dev-env-terragrunt.hcl

```
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
```

}

stage/terragrunt.hcl

```
remote_state {
  backend = "s3"
  generate = {
   path      = "backend.tf"
   if_exists = "overwrite"
```

}

```
config = {
  bucket  = 
  key     = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
  region   = "us-east-1
  encrypt = true
```

Below is my workflow code.

```
name: 'Terragrunt GitHub Actions
on:
  pull_request:
     branches:
     - test
  env:``
   tf_version: 'latest'
  tg_version: 'latest'
  tf_working_dir: 'stage/dev-env'
jobs:
  terragrunt:
   name: 'Terragrunt'
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
  - name: 'Terragrunt Init'
    uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
    with:
      tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
      tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
      tf_actions_subcommand: 'init'
      tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
      tf_actions_comment: true
    env:
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1'
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}

  - name: 'Terragrunt Validate'
    uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
    with:
      tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
      tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
      tf_actions_binary: 'terraform'
      tf_actions_subcommand: 'validate'
      tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
      tf_actions_comment: true
    env:
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
```

Comment: Please share your code and directory layout.

Comment: The very first error is _/github/workspace//stage/dev-env: No such file or directory_. Does this directory exist on whatever this is running on?

Comment: no,it doesnt exist but terragrunt documentation suggested if the workspace doesnt already exit then it will be created.I am running the code using GithubActions workflow

Comment: @BenWhaley   Hi,did you see my code and directory layout